# EF:Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to populate a grid control, and I get some errors like the content of the title when I try to make updates.

Error:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows ({0}). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

And I had made some attempts, for example:

1. Checked that the primary key is correct;
2. There have no such code like [`Bind(Exclude)]`;
3. I got that data from database before I maked it as modified;

And here it's my code:

```
var expProfitDtos = value.ExpProfits as List<FileExpProfitDto>;
if (expProfitDtos != null && expProfitDtos.Any(ep => ep.EditStatus == EditStatus.Added))
{
    GenerateFileExpProfitSorting(expProfitDtos, value.File);
}
expProfitDtos = expProfitDtos.OrderByDescending(c => c.EditStatus).ToList();
var expProfits = ProcessDetailsFileExpProfitEntityState<FileExpProfitDto>(expProfitDtos);
```

And the detail of `ProcessDetailsFileExpProfitEntityState`():

```
protected List<FileExpProfit> ProcessDetailsFileExpProfitEntityState<TDto>(List<TDto> dto, IMapper dtoToEntityMapper = null) where TDto : UpdatableDto 
        {
            if (dto == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            DbContext ctx = GetDbContext<FileExpProfit>();

            List<FileExpProfit> result = new List<FileExpProfit>();
            foreach (var dtoItem in dto)
            {
                FileExpProfit itemEntity = null;
                FileExpProfit itemCacheEntity = null;
                if (dtoToEntityMapper == null)
                {
                    itemCacheEntity = dtoItem.AutoMapper<FileExpProfit>();
                }
                else
                {
                    itemCacheEntity = dtoToEntityMapper.Map<FileExpProfit>(dtoItem);
                }

                if (dtoItem.EditStatus == EditStatus.Modified)
                {
                    itemEntity = DbContext.FileExpProfits
.Where(d => d.FileExpProfitID == itemCacheEntity.FileExpProfitID)
.FirstOrDefault();
                    itemEntity.GrpCode = itemCacheEntity.GrpCode;
                    itemEntity.UserID = itemCacheEntity.UserID;
                    //ctx.Set<FileExpProfit>().Attach(itemEntity);
                    ctx.Entry(itemEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    var bo=DbContext.SaveChanges() > 0;
                    Console.WriteLine(bo);
                }

                result.Add(itemEntity);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

There get the error when the program is executed this code: `DbContext.SaveChanges().`

Has anyone seen this or does anyone know what the error message refers to ?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Just  like the content of the title: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows ({0}). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like that I have get some ideas about this error, expect the most common solutions, we also need to consider the main table association problem of the updated data table. Before the table status is maked as modified, the main table has been maked as modified once, as a result, the table status is modified twice and the rowversion value is disaccord with the value in the database.